# Pass data from BottomSheetFragment to previous Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, bottom-sheet

Is there any better way to send back the data to the previous fragment/parent fragment other than listener?

I have a fragment which consists of list of items. Clicking on the items will open a bottom sheet fragment. While closing the bottom sheet popup I need to pass data back to the fragment itself.

What I have done so far is created a listener and implemented it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what components you're using. If you are using Android Jetpack components then check out this article: [LINK](https://proandroiddev.com/the-modern-way-to-pass-data-between-fragments-b305cabbf2f2)

You should be able to pass data back and forth similar to passing data with `startActivityForResult()`

Also, while you're at it please check out the official documentation too, there's a good example that will help you understand this better: [LINK](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate)

Answer (score 0):

Although you mention any way other than listener, but according to
documents:

> Starting with Fragment 1.3.0-alpha04, each FragmentManager
> implements FragmentResultOwner. This means that a FragmentManager can
> act as a central store for fragment results. This change allows
> components to communicate with each other by setting fragment results
> and listening for those results...
>
> Sets the FragmentResultListener for a given requestKey. Once the given
> LifecycleOwner is at least in the STARTED state, any results set by
> setFragmentResult using the same requestKey will be delivered to the
> callback. The callback will remain active until the LifecycleOwner
> reaches the DESTROYED state or clearFragmentResultListener is called
> with the same requestKey.

To pass data back to fragment A from fragment B, first set a result listener on fragment A, the fragment that receives the result. Call setFragmentResultListener() on fragment A's FragmentManager, as shown in below:

in your BottomSheet Class:

```
btncloseBottomSheet.setOnClickListener {
            val result = Bundle().apply {
                // put your data in bundle
                putInt("MY_KEY", 6)
            }
            setFragmentResult("requestCode", result)
            dismiss()
        }
```

in your previous fragment/parent fragment, you need to implement FragmentResultListener:

```
    class PreviousFragment : FragmentResultListener {
    ...
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            
            // set fragment listener
            parentFragmentManager.setFragmentResultListener(
                            "requestCode",
                            viewLifecycleOwner,
                            this
                    )
    
        }
    ...
    
    // get result from other fragments by FragmentResultListener
        override fun onFragmentResult(requestKey: String, result: Bundle) {
    
            when (requestKey) {
    
                "requestCode" -> {
                    val resultFromBundle = result.getInt("MY_KEY")
                    // Do somthing
                }
            }
    
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to pass data from the current `fragment/bottom sheet fragment` to the previous fragment/activity is -

> Bottom sheet Fragment from which we want to pass data

```
requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.setFragmentResult(
        "requested_data_key",
        Bundle().apply { 
             putString("value_one_key", "abc")
             putString("value_two_key", "xyz")
        }
)
```

> Activity/ Fragment where we need data

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
         setSelectedSchemeResultListener() 
    }
    
    private fun setSelectedSchemeResultListener() {
    Log.d("TAG11", "setSelectedSchemeResultListener: $supportFragmentManager")
    supportFragmentManager.setFragmentResultListener(SELECTED_SCHEME_ID, this) { _, bundle ->
        Log.d("TAG11", "setSelectedSchemeResultListener:${bundle[]} ")
        Log.d("TAG11", "setSelectedSchemeResultListener:value - ${bundle["value_one_key"]}")
    }
}
```