# How android fragment lifecycle when behind another fragment?

Tags: android, fragment, lifecycle

I wonder how android fragment lifecycle works when it is behind another fragment.

I want to update recyclerView after dismissing bottom sheet dialog fragment, i.e., application showed recyclerView fragment.

I tried Log.d to check lifecycle, but don't know how to do it correctly.

Comment: Maybe you could clarify what you mean a little bit. I couldn't understand what you mean by "How android fragment lifecycle when behind another fragment".

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the easiest way is to add listener to your bottom sheet and listen to events in your fragment. You can do it like this:

```
class MyBottomSheet : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    lateinit var onActionListener: () -> Unit

    fun action() {
        // your action
        onActionListener.invoke()
    }

}

class MyFragment : Fragment() {

    fun showDialog(fragmentManager: FragmentManager, tag: String?) {
        MyBottomSheet().apply { 
            onActionListener = {
                // your event listener
            }
            show(fragmentManager, tag)
        }
    }

}
```

To listen to fragment lifecycle changes you can use adb shell command like described in [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/debugging#fm-logging).

Moreover, you can find more ways to listen to events from bottom sheet dialog in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68408250/7974665).